# urlfetch change in April and simpleoauth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, oauth, urlfetch

I am using this [crhym3/simpleauth](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth) for oauth authentication with Google, Linkedin and Twitter in my project. It uses GAE's urlfetch.

Google is planning to change the behaviour of urlfetch in late April. I reproduce their notice here:

> Currently, the URL Fetch service preserves your original HTTP method
>   (e.g., GET, POST) when it receives and responds to a 302 Moved
>   Temporarily response. Modern user agents typically issue a GET request
>   in response to a 302. After the update, URL Fetch will only issue a
>   GET request after receiving a 302 response, rather than preserving the
>   original method. This may cause requests to be routed differently
>   and/or return 404s or other errors, and will drop the message body
>   from POST requests.

I have posted a question on the project's forum but I haven't got a reply yet.

My question is:

What is the best way to test this piece of software is safe from the change? I am thinking of adding `follow_redirects=False` to the urlfetch calls to see what redirections I get from google, linkedin and twitter.

Comment: Why do you think it would affect you at all? 302 response is not a part of any authentication flow.

Comment: If you are certain of it, why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

They are just following the specifications. I'm pretty sure that all of them (google, linkedin and twitter) are accepts GET request after redirect as its defined in the specifications.

So I think that you don't need to do anything.